# scss does not compile :root

Tags: sass, vuejs2, webpack-2

file a.scss:

```
$myVariable:#ffffff;
```

file b.scss:

```
@import './a.scss';

 //does not work
:root{
   --root-variable:$myVariable; 
}

//works
.myClass{
    color:$myVariable; 
}
```

The editor sees the value of **myVariable** in the **b.scss** file. But after compiling on the page, if you look at the properties, it looks like this:

> --root-variable:$myVariable

but expected:

> --root-variable:#ffffff

webpack:

```
{
  test: /\.vue$/,
  exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
  use: {
       loader: 'vue-loader',
       options: {
              loaders: {
                        scss: 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader', // <style lang="scss">
                        sass: 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?indentedSyntax' // <style lang="sass">
                        }
                 }
        }


}
```

How to fix it?

```
//UPDATE
```

I changed the question because I found the problem, but I still do not know how to solve it

Comment: are you using `<style lang="scss">` ?

Comment: @Jacob Goh, Yes

Comment: @Jacob Goh, I changed the question

Answer (score 6):

For anyone coming across this now, it was due to a change in Sass 3.5, which [is explained here](http://sass.logdown.com/posts/809572-sass-35-release-candidate).

Using Sass variables when defining custom CSS variables now needs to be done slightly differently. This used to work:

```
:root {
   --root-variable: $myVariable; 
}
```

But now you should now do this:

```
:root {
   --root-variable: #{$myVariable}; 
}
```